# Dependent checkbox on array input checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have two array checkboxes namely chk1 & chk2 this checkboxes data are generated *dynamically*. When i check chk1  **UK** means chk2 **90** has to be checked. if **US** means **60** has to be checked and so on. any suggestion to do this task?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="UK"> UK
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="US"> US
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="IN"> IN

<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="90"> 90
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="60"> 60
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="10"> 10
```

Comment: `id` should be unique for each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while you tagged Jquery you can use `.eq()` and `.index()`

```
$('input[name=chk1]').on('click' , function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
     $('input[name=chk2]').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked' , true);
  }else{
    $('input[name=chk2]').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked' , false);
  }
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/m9mv68ka/)

> **Note:** be sure to include jquery

Another way using `:eq()` selector with `.index()`

```
 $('input[name=chk2]:eq('+$(this).index()+')')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like following. Hope this will help you.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox][name=chk1]").change(function () {
    var status = this.checked;
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=chk2]").eq($(this).index()).prop('checked', status);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="UK"> UK
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="US"> US
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="IN"> IN

<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="90"> 90
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="60"> 60
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="10"> 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript

```
<input onclick='handleClick(this);' type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="UK"> UK
<input onclick='handleClick(this);' type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="US"> US
<input onclick='handleClick(this);' type="checkbox" name="chk3" id="chk3" value="IN"> IN

<input type="checkbox" name="chk4" id="chk4" value="90"> 90
<input type="checkbox" name="chk5" id="chk5" value="60"> 60
<input type="checkbox" name="chk6" id="chk6" value="10"> 10
<script>
  function handleClick(cb) {

    switch (cb.name) {
      case "chk1":
        document.getElementById("chk4").checked = cb.checked;
        break;
      case "chk2":
        document.getElementById("chk5").checked = cb.checked;
        break;
      case "chk3":
        document.getElementById("chk6").checked = cb.checked;
        break;
    }
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My own solution for this task

```js
$(document).on('click' ,'input[name=chk1]', function(){
 $("input[name=chk1]").each(function(i) {
  if($(this).is(":checked"))
    $('input[name=chk2]:eq('+i+')').prop('checked' , true);
  else
    $('input[name=chk2]:eq('+i+')').prop('checked' , false);
 });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="UK"> UK
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="US"> US
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1" id="chk1" value="IN"> IN
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="90"> 90
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="60"> 60
<input type="checkbox" name="chk2" id="chk2" value="10"> 10
```